# how to separate app.use to different file

Tags: node.js, express

I would like add these two `app.use(express.urlencode({extended:true})); app.use (express.json());` lines into separate file. I am not getting how to call these lines from another file

```
import express from 'express';
import routes from './routes.js';
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.use(express.urlencode({extended:true}));
app.use (express.json());
app.use('/', routes);

 app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Comment: I think you could use Router, import it into the file where do you want to use it and use Router instead of the app here, and then export it back to the index file.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate it like this:

`index.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

require("./routes")(app);
// rest of your code
```

Then create `routes.js` in the same folder with `index.js`, and fill it with something like this:

```js
const express = require("express");

module.exports = function (app) {
   app.use(express.urlencode({extended:true}));
   app.use(express.json());
}
```

That's it! What you need is just pass the `app` to `routes.js`, and execute it in `routes.js`.